# Gradle Build Issue with nebula-release plugin

Tags: gradle, build, nebula

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'novatti-vms-database'.

  > Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing
  >   Stage rc is not one of [dev] allowed for strategy development.

Does anyone have any idea about it, its only happening with one of my project and tried to check the configs its all similar to other projects.

Comment: I'm currently running into the same error. In my case it seems to be bound to the naming of my gradle project. Projects that end with "-service" work fine, but projects with the "-server" suffix throws the error you mentioned on each and every task I try to run. Did you perhaps find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think i found the solution for this one, as candidate, final can't work on the uncommitted files. so what was happening is for me it was creating a build folder and some .gradle folder which was not commited.

I added those to .gitignore and committed the .gitignore. Which means these files are ignored and worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some trial and error I managed to find what's causing this problem.
For me this error was caused by the use of a forward slash in my branch name in Git.
See: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin/issues/46

For example: when I'm on the branch "develop" everything works as it should, but when I switch to "feature/stuff" the error occurred again.

Please note that it's best to run gradle 's clean task to make the error fully disappear after you switched branches. In the meantime you can work arround the problem by commenting the line

```
nebula.nebula-release
```

When you're ready to commit just uncomment it. Or you could wait for release 4.1.0, but that might take a while.